# PRAAT create string array and search in that array

Tags: praat

It seems like an easy task (and is easy in other languages), but Im having trouble finding a solution.

Is it possible to create an array of strings? I'm looking for a PRAAT equivalent of the following python code

```
options=["a","b","cd"]
```

The ultimate goal is to do something like

```
Input=["ab","cd","ef"]
for InputEle in Input
    if InputEle is in options
        do blah
    endif
endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a string vector:

```
options$# = {"a", "b", "cd"}
for i from 1 to 3
   appendInfoLine: options$# [i]
endfor
```

Check out section 8 at https://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Scripting_5_7__Vectors_and_matrices.html